# How to access TextArea's text and/or change it?

Tags: sapui5

#### XML View

```xml
<TextArea id="message"
  maxLength="100"
  width="100%"
  valueLiveUpdate="true"
  showExceededText="false"
  placeholder="Type here.."
  required="true"
/>
```

#### Controller

```js
onInit: function() {
  // ...
  this.getView().byId("message").setText("");
},
```

Here I tried two commands to clear the text area values. But got error

- `this.getView().byId("message").setText("");`

  > TypeError: this.getView(...).byId(...).setText is not a function
- `sap.ui.getCore().byId("message").setText("");`

  > TypeError: sap.ui.getCore(...).byId(...) is undefined.

How to clear TextArea values from JS?

Comment: In case there is no clarity which `byId`-API to use, take a look at ["Difference Between `this.getView().byId()`, `this.byId()`, and `sap.ui.getCore().byId()`
"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48640283/5846045)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The control [`sap.m.TextArea`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.TextArea/controlProperties) doesn't have the *text* property and thus no such mutator and accessor either. Instead, the text value can be set via the property `value` since the control [extends InputBase](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/controlProperties).

Therefore, the line should be:

```
this.byId("message").setValue();
```