# SAPUI5: How can I reset/clear a TextArea oder Date-Field

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i need help with the above question.

To clear a normal `Textfield` works very well. example code:

```
_resetButton: function () {
    var InputField = this.byId("idInputField");
    InputField.setValueState("None");
    InputField.setValueStateText(null);
}
```

but for `TextArea` or `DatePicker` field it doesn't work.

Have anybody an idea how i can set Value `null`

i have tried it with `setValue()` or `setText()` but without success.

Best regard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access TextArea's text and/or change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189699/how-to-access-textareas-text-and-or-change-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/wedenel/edit?js,output)

```
setValue("")
```

They all inherit from `sap.m.InputBase` and there is a `setValue()`