# Get Current Focused Element

Tags: sapui5

How can I get the element with the currently active focus in a SimpleForm?
I have already tried with [`getFocusInfo()`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/getFocusInfo), but I have information if the element I try to select has an active focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current focused control like this:

### UI5 1.119+

```js
// Element required from "sap/ui/core/Element"
Element.getActiveElement();
```

[API Reference: `sap.ui.core.Element.getActiveElement`](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element%23methods/sap.ui.core.Element.getActiveElement)

### UI5 < 1.119

```js
// Core required from "sap/ui/core/Core"
getCurrentFocusedControl: function() {
  const currentFocusedControlId = Core.getCurrentFocusedControlId(); // deprecated since 1.119
  return Core.byId(currentFocusedControlId); // deprecated since 1.119
},
```

[API Reference: `sap.ui.core.Core#getCurrentFocusedControlId`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Core#methods/getCurrentFocusedControlId)

Comment: `getCurrentFocusedControlId()` might also return `null` (when currently no element has the focus).

Comment: @user1364368 The new API `Element.getActiveElement()` now documents that it could return `undefined` as well: https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element%23methods/sap.ui.core.Element.getActiveElement