Error extending SAP standard Fiori Elements App
I am trying to extend a standard SAP Fiori Elements App which uses Fiori Elements extensions.
For what is worth, the App I am trying to extend is "Manage Purchase Requisition Professional":
https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('F2229')/S28OP
And, when trying to run the extended app (either locally or through a tile in FLP), I see an error in the console:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setProperty')

This is happening in the original App's controller (ListReportExt > onInit), as it fails to fetch the objects from their IDs:
var currDetBtn = sap.ui.getCore().byId("ui.s2p.mm.profrequisition.maintains1::sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ListReport.view.ListReport::C_PurchaseReqnHeader--action::ActionCurrDetbutton");
var listReportTbl = sap.ui.getCore().byId("ui.s2p.mm.profrequisition.maintains1::sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ListReport.view.ListReport::C_PurchaseReqnHeader--responsiveTable");

What seems strange is that the IDs point the original App (ui.s2p.mm.profrequisition.maintains1) but are not found/seen - I assume they would be found, as I am simply extending it.
Just to confirm, I resolved all dependencies of the original App before all my local tests. I also made sure all parameters on the extended App were the same as the original App when running it through FLP, but unfortunately the behavior did not change.
So, do you have any hints here to help me extending this App?
Thanks

Are the target elements (currDetBtn, listReportTbl) defined by your extension project? Extensions should not access elements created by the base app unless they're documented. See the "SAP Fiori elements guidelines" section in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48640283/5846045

Thanks for the answer! Actually those elements are defined in the original App - the one I am trying to extend. It uses Fiori Elements extensions, and it has the target elements in its manifest under extensions.
Also, the error is thrown on the original App's controller - this is happening in the original App's controller (ListReportExt > onInit), as I am trying to just make my own extension work before adding any changes.
Thank you!

If the issue is observed in the base application, I'd suggest to create a ticket at SAP with the application component MM-FIO-PUR-REQ-PRF.
